# Probability distribution - consumption of pigs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If you eat $10$ pigs in $40\%$ of the weeks, $7$ pigs in $27\%$ of the weeks and $5$ pigs in $33\%$ of the weeks while cooking $10$ pigs at the beginning of the week to have sufficient supply (the uneaten pigs are thrown out), what is the probability distribution of the weekly consumption of pigs?

Would it be $0.4 \cdot 10+ 0.27 \cdot 7+ 0.33 \cdot 5$? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  It seems to me that you are calculating the expected number of pigs that are consumed in a week.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, but I'm not sure if I should be multiplying the numbers or do a weighted average of them.